# Lag function on Table Visual on AWS QuickSight

Tags: amazon-web-services, calculated-field, amazon-quicksight

I am new to AWS QuickSight and I am trying to use the cumulative percent of sales from last month up to the same day as a given date. At first, it seemed straightforward to me. I have a Table Visual with Loan Date and the Month Ratio (which is an aggregation with RunningSum within the month divided by the total of the month). My Table Visual looks like this:

Loan Date | RunningSum(Loan Amount) | Total Loan in Month | Month Ratio
01-MAY-2020 | $1,000 | $50,000 | 0.02
02-MAY-2020 | $2,500 | $50,000 | 0.05
...
30-MAY-2020 | $48,000 | $50,000 | 0.96
31-MAY-2020 | $50,000 | $50,000 | 1.00
01-JUN-2020 | $3,000 | $60,000 | 0.05
...

I wanted to create a calculated field so that Lagged Month ratio for 01-JUN-2020 would be the value at 01-MAY-2020 (0.02 in my example), for 01-JUN-2020 it would be the value at 02-MAY-2020, and so on. If a month does not have the 31st day, for instance, it would just return a NULL value. I  have tried the following calculated field:

lag({Month ratio}, [{Loan Date} ASC], dateDiff(addDateTime(-1, 'MM', {Loan Date}),{Loan Date},'DD'))

But AWS QuickSight just says my calculated field contains an error (it underlines the "l" from "lag") and asks me to try again ("We encountered an error trying to save your calculated field. Please try creating it again.").

Can anyone help me? I couldn't find it in AWS-QuickSight Documentation.